# Supremum and Limit superior

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let $g_n$ be a sequence of functions, f a function.

Why, in general, is $$\sup_n(g_n\circ f)\ne\sup_n(g_n)\circ f$$
while $$\limsup_n(g_n\circ f)=\limsup_n(g_n)\circ f$$
holds?

Comment: What is the sup of a set of functions?

Comment: I supposed $f_n, g$ be real functions.
$[\sup_n(g_n\circ f)](x)=\sup_n \begin{Bmatrix}g_n\circ f(x)\end{Bmatrix}$

Comment: So, you consider everything elementwise, I assume. Then $\sup_n f_n = \sup_n g_n$ means that $\sup_n f_n(x) = \sup_n g_n(x)$ for every $x$?

Comment: If for a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions you define $(\sup_n f_n)(x) := \sup_n f_n(x)$, then the first inequality you have is wrong. They are equal.